# Java class deleted and compiled again but still does not change?

Tags: java

I have deleted Java class and compiled again after making changes to some image files but the changes are not still reflecting when run!

The code is rather large so I cannot post them here but is there a reason why? Do I need to use decompiler to decompile them rather than deleting?

Comment: You definitely don't need to decompile.  Are you sure your compilation is successful?  Are you sure you're running the classes that were generated, and not accidentally referring to an older version of the classes in the wrong directory?

Comment: Did you do Project->Clean then see if that works?

Comment: I'm getting this error when I compile: Note: Absolute.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: @Jae That's not an error, a warning rather. Try using `-Xlint:deprecation` option to see what it really is.

Comment: @Choi For the record, decompiling will not "undo the compile". Whatever was compiled will still exist. In theory, you can compile some source code to get a class file, and then decompile that class file to get that source code back. If you did this, you'd have 3 files: original source, compiled class, and decompiled source. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a decompiler won't help you here.  Either you're compiling the wrong `.java` files or you're loading the wrong `.class` files.

Run `java` with `-verbose:class` to get a dump of where classes are loaded from.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dyn0429/

> Setting the parameter `-verbose:class` on the java command line prints a trace of the class loading process. Listing 3 shows partial output from running the Listing 2 program with this parameter:
>
> Listing 3. Partial `-verbose:class` output
>
> ```
> ...
> [Loaded java.lang.Object from /usr/java/j2sdk1.4.1/jre/lib/rt.jar]
> ...
> ```

Comment: I could not run this as it came with could not find main class error

Answer (score 1):

If you deleted the Java source file, then you shouldn't expect the the class file to be removed when you re-compile. You would have to "clean" up your build. Usually Eclipse and other tools do this for you, or provide a "clean" command so you may force it.

Comment: When I open .java file it does not allow me to Clean as this option is disabled

Comment: You clean your project, not individual files. Clean means to delete files that are generated by the compiler and other build processes.

Answer (score 0):

Every time this has happened to me, the solution has been trivial, and I'd been doing something really stupid.  50% of the time I'd looked straight at the problem and not seen it.  The other 50% the problem was in an area I had thought absolutely dependable, usually of my own creation.

To solve this you must be absolutely paranoid.  Make sure you are thoroughly backed up before doing any of this.  Then, use your operating system to delete files, not your IDE.  Check to make sure they are deleted, using the OS *and* the IDE.  Scan your disk for other copies of the class file and rename them.  Scan for other copies of the java file, and rename *them*.  Rename the java file you *think* you are using and make sure you get an error.  Check the date on the class file.  Run your program straight from the operating system with your own, typed-in classpath.  Better still, put all the classes in a new directory and run from there.  (Java might be finding hidden files the OS and the IDE won't tell you about.)  Change your java file in truly dramatic ways--its possible your code changes don't actually do anything.

I can't really tell you what to do, only put you in the right frame of mind.  Either the problem is outside the area you think it is in, or you can't see it when you look at it.  So you need to expand the search boundaries, question everything, and don't assume a step is working right just because you've looked at it once or twice.

Also, go do something else for a while.  The solution may hit you from no where and save you a lot of work.  I have found working for a while and then doing something else gets the best results, but when in the middle of problem its hard to know which to do..